# Proper way of notating nested expression whose value is 1

Tags: recreational-mathematics, lambert-w

Trying to express $x=1$ in the following way, replacing its value recursively, but it's not clear that it "converges" properly

$$x=-e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{...}}}}}}}}$$

any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: There might be something interesting going on here, but you need to be clear on two things: how the limit is being taken, and what convention you are using for the square root. Also, it's possible you want a negative sign in front of *each* $e$, not just the first one.

Comment: just the first one ... using that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and that $-1=e^{\pi i}$

Comment: Is your question answered or something left ?

Comment: @user90369, your square roots are all being taken of positive real numbers, so nothing negative or imaginary ever makes an appearance (until the very end), unless you're using some weird convention that takes the *negative* square root of one (or more) of your positive reals. As currently stated, with the usual conventions for square roots and towers of powers, what you've presented is divergent.

Comment: @BarryCipra : You are taking this question too serious, the background of the topic is *recreational-mathematics* (means: *Puzzles, curiosities, brain teasers and other mathematics done "just for fun".*). So, of course, it doesn't make sense to compute infinite PowerTower for real values $>e^{1/e}$ . The OP is looking for a formal presentation (that's what I've understood) and that's what he has got. (My question was about my answering his question, not about your question.)

Comment: @user90369, sorry, I meant to "@" the OP, not you.

Comment: @BarryCipra : O.k. . But please: The question of the OP is a game, not something serious (only just for fun).

Comment: @user90369, I'm all in favor of having fun. For me, part of the fun is in understanding what goes wrong (and sometimes right) when you make unwarranted assumptions.

Comment: @BarryCipra : Maybe the OP still explains the background of his question ... . ;) Then you can find out what is wrong with his question.

Comment: @BarryCipra and user90369 thanks for the helpful comments ... background was on was just riffing on recursively replacing $i$ with $\sqrt{-1}$ using that $-1=e^{\pi i}$ ... the recursion doesn't seem to be notated in such a way that it "converges" (in the recreational sense) ... was hoping for some insight on how to more properly express it ... you've provided that

Comment: @user90369 and BarryCipra thanks for the helpful comments ... background was on was just riffing on recursively replacing $i$ with $\sqrt{-1}$ using that $-1=e^{\pi i}$ ... the recursion doesn't seem to be notated in such a way that it "converges" (in the recreational sense) ... was hoping for some insight on how to more properly express it ... you've provided that

Comment: No problem, it was a pleasure!  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use $~i^{1/i}=e^{\pi/2}$ . $~$ Let $~T(x)~$ the $~$*infinite power tower*$~$

(e.g. see [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) and [PowerTower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html)) then for real $~x~$ it's $~T(x^{1/x})=x~$ if $~\frac{1}{e}<x<e$ .

Now we can $~$*formally*$~$ write $~T(i^{1/i})=i~$ and therefore:

> $$-e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{...}}}}}}}}=-T(e^{\pi/2})^2=-T(i^{1/i})^2=-i^2=1$$

*Note:*

$\displaystyle T(x)=\frac{W(-\ln x)}{-\ln x}~$ where $W$ represents *Lambert's W function* .

[Here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertsche_W-Funktion) you can read, that $~\displaystyle W\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=i\frac{\pi}{2}~$ as a unique assignment so that $~\displaystyle T(e^{\pi/2})=-i~$ .

Answer (score 4):

Let $x_0=e^\pi$ and define the sequence $x_n$ recursively by

$$x_{n+1}=e^{\pi\sqrt{x_n}}$$

If you **assume** the limit $L=\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n$ exists, then it must satisfy the equation

$$L=e^{\pi\sqrt{L}}$$

Now $L=-1$ does satisfy that equation, since $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}=e^{\pi i}=-1$, so it's tempting to conclude, as the OP wants, that

$$1=-e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{e^{\pi\sqrt{...}}}}}}}}$$

However, this conclusion contradicts the very assumption it's predicated upon.  That's because the numbers $x_n$ are, if you use the usual convention that the square root of a positive real is a positive real, all positive reals, and such a sequence cannot only have a nonnegative real number as a limit.

We could ask if the equation $L=e^{\pi\sqrt{L}}$ has some *other* solution with $L\ge0$. With a bit of calculus, it's possible to show it doesn't. So the sequence of $x_n$'s does not have a limit; it diverges.